# Is my proof correct for bijectivity of this finction?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**Theorem:** prove that $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}_k\times \mathbb{N}$ by $f(n)=(m,n), \forall m\in \mathbb{N}_k, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ is bijective.
**My attempt:** $\forall n_1, n_2\in \mathbb{N}$ let $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$. Then $(m,n_1)=(m,n_2)$. Therefore $n_1=n_2$ and hence $f$ is injective.
$f$ is obviously serjective, because $\forall (m,n)\in \mathbb{N}_k\times \mathbb{N}, f(n)=(m,n)$ since $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So $f$ is bijective.

**Is my proof correct? Is the theorem correct at all**

Comment: I'd say you meant $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Anyway, if the first component $m$ is fixed, how can it be bijective? Or am I misunderstanding that definition?

Comment: @MickG: Yes, that was a typo. Corrected it. I don't know, maybe the theorem be wrong at all!

Comment: If you define $f$ to be $f(n)=(m,n)$ with a fixed $m\in\mathbb{N}_k$ and $n$ varying in $\mathbb{N}$, then take $m'\neq m$ but still in $\mathbb{N}_k$ and for no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you have $(m',n)$ is an image of $f$, so $f$ is not surjective. **Note**: the above comment by Sisabe was posted while I typed this.

Comment: Your function not well defined

Comment: @Hamou: So how to edit it to be well defined?

Comment: @MickG: So how to edit it to be a bijective function?

Comment: It's more complicated than it looks :). Better define it the other way round. You should use the diagonal trick used to prove there is such a bijection. So you create an infinite table with columns from $k$ to infinity and rows from 1 (or 0 if $\mathbb{N}\ni0$ for you, and I'm assuming $\mathbb{N}_k$ means the integers not less than $k$) to infinity and the crossings of rows and columns are pairs in $\mathbb{N}_k\times\mathbb{N}$, you go through the whole table by starting at $(k,0)$, going right by one, going diagonally down, down by one, diagonally up, etc. I wouldn't know how to give an…

Comment: …expression for that though, nor even if a closed form actually exists for this.