# Can you define a bijective function from $\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}_k\times \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Can you define a simple bijective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}_k\times \mathbb{N}$ (or from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}_k$)?
P.s.: $\mathbb{N}_k=\{1,2,3,\cdots, k\}$

Comment: FYI, your $\mathbb{N}_k$ is normally written as $[k]$ in combinatorics.

Comment: uhm - yes. Start, e.g., by mapping $\{1,2,\ldots, k\}$ to $(1,1), (2,1), \ldots (k,1)$ (if you start counting in $\mathbb{N}$ at $1$)

Comment: @Thomas: Is $f(n)=(n,1), \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$  bijective?

Comment: No. The next step would be to map $k+1$ to $(1,2)$, then, $k+2$ to $(2, 2)$ and ($\ldots$) $2k$ to $(k,2)$. Then $ 2k+1$ to $(1,3)$, $2k+2$ to $(2,3)$. Can you recognize the pattern?

Comment: @Thomas: I'd like to have a formula for $f$. Can you give me one?

Comment: You have now enough hints to find the answer on your own, in particular if you take into account the extension of Chappers answer.

Comment: @Thomas: If I could find such a formula, I wouldn't ask this question here. I'm newbie in number theory, so please help me.

Comment: This could be of use to you https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable

Comment: @Sisabe Yes, I got that. Several people took their time to give you valuable and helpful hints. You should now sit down for a while and have a look at these hints to see how they could help you to find the answer. Or wait until someone else who wants to earn cheap upvotes will give you a complete answer. I won't.

Comment: @Thomas: I asked a similar question yesterday (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432327), but I can't find a simple formula for $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: modular arithmetic provides an essentially trivial function.

(In particular, the [Euclidean division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) produces, for each $n \in \{0,1,2,3,\dotsc\}$, a unique $q \in \{0,1,2,3,\dotsc\}$ and $r \in \{ 1,2,3,\dotsc,k-1 \}$ so that $n=qk+r$. You can then fiddle this around to get the particular bijection you want.)

Comment: This is what I had in mind, too. :-) +$1$

Comment: @Clayton Perhaps we should think outside the box a bit more ... :)

Comment: Could you please give me an example?